# Formatting of toc title in KOMA

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have read in other posts that I should not combine `KOMA` and `tocloft`. Therefore, I have rewritten my preamble, so that I'm formatting my toc in `KOMA` only. There is one (probably very easy) problem, however, which I cannot solve. How can I change the font of the title of the toc?
All other chapter titles are set as `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\uppercase}`. However, I have no clue how to change the title *Table of contents* (or *Inhaltsverzeichnis* in German accordingly), so that it looks like *Kapitel 1*.
I have checked the documentation of the KOMA-script itself and have read every posting I could find on similar questions online. Most of them concern the formatting of the entries of the toc, yet not the title itself.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, fontsize=10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap, toc=chapterentrywithdots, toc=flat]{scrbook}

%======================================
% === Papierformat ===
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

% === Schriftart ===
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% === Einzüge ===
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

%======================================
% === language packages ===
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% #russian nicht gefunden
% #griechisch fehlt greek.polutonik,russian,

%======================================
% === testing ===
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%======================================
% === headings  ===
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering} %Überschriften global zentrieren
\setkomafont{disposition}{\selectfont} %dieselbe Schriftart in Überschriften

%%kapiteltitel anpassen mit entsprechender grösse, grossbuchstaben bzw. kursivsetzung und linksausrichtung
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\uppercase} 
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\uppercase}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\itshape} 
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\raggedright} 

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ %%zusätzliche Abstände vor und nach Titeln, damit am anfang des textes kein einzug steht, könnte man afterindent=false ergänzen, aber das scheint sich auf die folgetitel auszuwirken
afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=3\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{paragraph}


%======================================
%======================================
%======================================
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{5}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % bis und mit Subsubsection nummerieren
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % bis und mit Paragraph

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter

\setcounter{page}{19}

\chapter{Kapitel 1}

\section{Titel 1}

\blindtext

\subsection{Subtitel 1}

\blindtext

\chapter{Kapitel 2}

\section{Titel 2}

\blindtext

\subsection{Subtitel 2}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `\makeuppercase` or `\MakeUppercase` or `\raggedright` in the argument of `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. Note that only font settings should be used there.

You can redefine `\chapterlinesformat` and `\sectionlinesformat` to get the desired result:

```latex
\NewCommandCopy{\originalchapterlinesformat}{\chapterlinesformat}
\NewCommandCopy{\originalsectionlinesformat}{\sectionlinesformat}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterlinesformat}{ m m m }{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sectionlinesformat}{ m m m m }{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{\raggedright}{}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
```

[image]

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, fontsize=10.2pt, DIV=calc, listof=nochaptergap, toc=chapterentrywithdots, toc=flat]{scrbook}

%======================================
% === Papierformat ===
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
  outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
  headsep=0.62cm,
  %textheight=19cm,textwidth=11.9cm% over-specification
]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
%\setlength{\textheight}{19cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel nicht an geometry vorbei ändern!!

% === Schriftart ===
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% === Einzüge ===
\setparsizes{6mm}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}% do not change \parindent manually

%======================================
% === language packages ===
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%======================================
% === testing ===
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%======================================
% === headings  ===
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering} %Überschriften global zentrieren
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor} %dieselbe Schriftart in Überschriften

%%kapiteltitel anpassen mit entsprechender grösse, grossbuchstaben bzw. kursivsetzung und linksausrichtung
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\itshape}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalchapterlinesformat}{\chapterlinesformat}
\NewCommandCopy{\originalsectionlinesformat}{\sectionlinesformat}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterlinesformat}{ m m m }{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sectionlinesformat}{ m m m m }{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{\raggedright}{}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=3\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth} % bis und mit Subsubsection nummerieren
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\paragraphtocdepth} % bis und mit Paragraph

%======================================
%======================================
%======================================
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Additional remarks:

Do not change `\textheight` and `\textwidth` outside of the `geometry` settings. Additionally they would result in an over-specification.

Do not change `\parindent` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

`\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase <ToC title>}`

and use `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase`

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase} % 
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase} %
```

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[twoside, fontsize=10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap, toc=chapterentrywithdots, toc=flat]{scrbook}

%======================================
% === Papierformat ===
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

% === Schriftart ===
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% === Einzüge ===
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

%======================================
% === language packages ===
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% #russian nicht gefunden
% #griechisch fehlt greek.polutonik,russian,

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase Inhaltsverzeichnis} % added <<<<<<<

%======================================
% === testing ===
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%======================================
% === headings  ===
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering} %Überschriften global zentrieren
\setkomafont{disposition}{\selectfont} %dieselbe Schriftart in Überschriften
%
%%%kapiteltitel anpassen mit entsprechender grösse, grossbuchstaben bzw. kursivsetzung und linksausrichtung
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{11.9pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<,


\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\itshape} 
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\fontsize{10.2pt}{11.9pt}\selectfont\raggedright} 

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ %%zusätzliche Abstände vor und nach Titeln, damit am anfang des textes kein einzug steht, könnte man afterindent=false ergänzen, aber das scheint sich auf die folgetitel auszuwirken
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=3\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
afterskip=1\baselineskip]{paragraph}


%======================================
%======================================
%======================================
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{page}{5}
    
    
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % bis und mit Subsubsection nummerieren
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % bis und mit Paragraph
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \setcounter{page}{19}
    
    \chapter{Kapitel 1}
    
    \section{Titel 1}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \subsection{Subtitel 1}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \chapter{Kapitel 2}
    
    \section{Titel 2}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \subsection{Subtitel 2}
    
    \blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

Used  `scrbook 2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script document class (book)`